# Variable created in stateless widget cannot be used in child widgets (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I'm quite new to Flutter and I face a problem. You probably can help!

The error message is:

```
Undefined name 'myObjectList'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
```

And the code:

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class myObject {
  const myObject({this.objectName, this.added, this.price});

  // final int id;
  // final int userId;
  final String objectName;
  // final String category;
  // final DateTime purchase;
  final DateTime added;
  final double price;
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // Mock data for objects (later to be retrieved from back-end)
    const List<myObject> myObjectList = [
      const myObject(objectName: 'TV', added: null, price: 12.25),
      const myObject(objectName: 'Nintendo Switch', added: null, price: 122)
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "The Safe",
      home: objectInventory(),
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey),
    );
  }
}

class objectInventory extends StatefulWidget {
  _objectInventoryState createState() => _objectInventoryState();
}

class _objectInventoryState extends State<objectInventory> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('The Safe')), body: myObjectList);
  }
} // End of _objectInventoryState
```

I would like to define my mock data into the MyApp class. Indeed, later on, I would like to retrieve data from the back-end at app launch.
Is there a way to make those data "global"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I defined the list outside of all functions/class. Doing this, I can access it from everywhere and can populate the list within a specific class.

In my case, the initial load of the list will be done in the class 'MyApp'.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class myObject {
  myObject({this.objectName, this.added, this.price});

  // final int id;
  // final int userId;
  final String objectName;
  // final String category;
  // final DateTime purchase;
  final DateTime added;
  final double price;

}

List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    //List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>();
    // Mock data for objects (later to be retrieved from back-end)
    myObjectList.add(
      myObject(objectName: 'TV', added: null, price: 12.25)
    );
    myObjectList.add(
      myObject(objectName: 'Nintendo Switch', added: null, price: 122)
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      title: "The Safe",
      home: objectInventory(),
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey),
    );
  }
}

class objectInventory extends StatefulWidget {
  objectInventoryState createState() => objectInventoryState();
}

class objectInventoryState extends State<objectInventory> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(appBar: AppBar(title: Text('The Safe')), body: Text(myObjectList[1].objectName) );
  }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`myObjectList` is declared inside the body of a method, you should declare it outside, inside the class

Like this:

```
List<myObject> myObjectList = new List<myObject>();
```

**UPDATE**

Inside the state you can access the `StatlessWidget` instance using widget field. So it becomes like this:

```
.... body: this.widget.myObjectList   ....
```

Comment: Thank you. I did change to include the list definition outside of the method, but inside the class (myApp). However, in the stateful _objectInventoryState, I cannot access this list. It is still considered as undefined and using your notation throws an error that the getter of myObjectList isn't defined for the class objectInventory.